# Java Cannot find Symbol in Another Class

Tags: java, class, variables, class-hierarchy

I'm trying to create a simple math function that makes use of a few other classes. One class is named `iRect` and has a few int values referring to the coordinates of two corners of a rectangle, and another class called `iPoint`, which only has two integer values for x and y coordinates. There is a third class that contains the main method, and all I'm trying to do is assign some values from instances of these classes to values within the main class.

For instance, when I use the code `iPoint bFt = new iPoint()` to initialize a new iPoint, the compiler has no problems with this. However, when I try to assign the x value from another iPoint that was successfully initialized to `bFt`, simply by typing out `bFt.x = iRectInstance.leftPoint1X;` Both of these items are of the same type, but my compiler is telling me that it can't find the variable `leftPoint1X` in the `iRect` class, even though when I go over there and check, the field int `leftPoint1X` is right there after the opening bracket, and `iRect` itself is in the same folder as the main file. Does anyone know what the cause of this could be?.

Comment: You need `x.leftPoint1X`, where `x` is some variable holding a reference to an instance of `iRect`.

Comment: it will be great if you share code!

Comment: um..... consider showing us your code.... maybe? Or I suppose we could guess what it looks like, but we're usually pretty bad at that.

Comment: As an aside, you will want to learn and use [Java naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). Variable names should all begin with a lower letter while class names with an upper case letter. Learning this and following this will allow us to better understand your code, and would allow you to better understand the code of others. Also your fields should be private and accessible in a controlled way via getters and setters.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the accessibility of the fields you are trying to evaluate (from another class) are public.

[Java Access Modifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Comment: Every class I'm using is public. Is this not enough?

Comment: No, making the class public just makes it available to things outside your current package, the fields must also be set with public access modifiers.